# Chain isomers of hexane

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why does hexane just have 5 chain isomers when I can think of more, like 2,2,3-trimethylbutane?
That's just one of the top of my head, I could think of more.

Comment: Trimethylbutane has 7 carbons, not 6.

Answer (score 1):

The list

- n-hexane
- 2-methylpentane
- 3-methylpentane
- 2,2-dimethylbutane
- 2,3-dimethylbutane

is definitely exhaustive.